# How to Configure the Google Maps for Rails Map config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using the GM4Rails Gem.

I'm very newbie to Rails and I'm trying to find the config file so I can get a HYBRID Google Maps instead of the ROADMAP.

I couldn't find the file: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map

Is there anyway I can change the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to know that:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

is a shortcut for:

```
<%= gmaps("map_options" => { "auto_adjust" => true},
          "markers"     => { "data" => @json }) 
 %>
```

When you need to pass additional options, **you have to use the `gmaps` helper**. In your case:

```
<%= gmaps("map_options" => { "auto_adjust" => true, "type" => "HYBRID" },
          "markers"     => { "data" => @json }) 
 %>
```

As you saw many more options are available.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working. I didn't know that gmaps4rails was a shortcut for the extended gmaps(...) method.

I think my tip for other beginner is to create a helper that encapsulates all the other options in a HELPER method so the code stay DRY in the VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the `Gmaps.loadMaps();` function directly, use:

```
search_map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.search_map = search_map;
search_map.map_options.raw.streetViewControl = false; // yes, raw
// more options
search_map.map_options.id = "search_map";
search_map.map_options.maxZoom = 14;
search_map.map_options.zoom = 12;
Gmaps.loadMaps();
```

I am not too sure about the rest of the code (it's from an old codebase), but the line you are looking for is `search_map.map_options.raw.streetViewControl = false;`

Answer (score -1):

So to display a map you use something like the code below:

```
    <%= gmaps({
          "map_options" => {"container_id" => "connections_map_container", "auto_adjust" => "true", "bounds" => '[{"lat": 0, "lng": 0 }, {"lat": 80 , "lng": 100 }]'},
          ... #add here data you want to display
          })
 %>
```

This is where you pass in your map options, so anywhere on that line you would insert `"type" =>             "HYBRID"`

So the modified example would look like

```
    <%= gmaps({
          "map_options" => {"container_id" => "connections_map_container", "auto_adjust" => "true", "bounds" => '[{"lat": 0, "lng": 0 }, {"lat": 80 , "lng": 100 }]'}, "type" => "HYBRID"
          ... #add here data you want to display
          })
 %>
```